# .NET Core project - Exclude files from single file publishment

Tags: c#, .net-core, build, publish

I would like to exclude nuget dlls from single file deployment but I do not know what am I doing wrong.

My current .csproj is this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Principal.Windows" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Newtonsoft.Json.dll">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Method I tried is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview#exclude-files-from-being-embedded

Comment: Unfortunately, this is currently not possible: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25411

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a .Net single file, without the DLLs of the NuGet packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77911350/building-a-net-single-file-without-the-dlls-of-the-nuget-packages)

Answer (score 0):

This might be old but I did encounter this problem and I fixed it myself.

```
</PropertyGroup>
  <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\DLControls\DLControls.csproj">
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </ProjectReference>
<ItemGroup>
```

If `ProjectReference` works then the `PackageReference` should work too

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not yet supported for `PackageReference`