# Building a .Net single file, without the DLLs of the NuGet packages

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-8.0

I have a C# .NET 8.0 project, with a lot of referenced NuGet packages.

Now, I would like to build it as a single `.exe`, with separated .dll's of the NuGet packages.

Until now, the MSBuild process generates several files: .application, .deps.json, .dll, .dll.manifest, .exe, .pdb and .runtimeconfig.json for my project.

Inside the `.csproj` file in the `<PropertyGroup>`, I defined the following:

```
<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
```

But this generates one `.exe` without separated .dll files for the NuGet packages.

I expect a file size about 5 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [selectively exclude files from the *PublishSingleFile*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#exclude-files-from-being-embedded) process, but not if they are bundled in as *Package References*. If this is important then you need to use the old *AssemblyReference* approach, then you can use can exclude the assembly explicitly. This is my example project file, note that I have one package reference that is bundled, and the `NModbus` package is not bundled:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NModbus">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\.nuget\packages\nmodbus\3.0.81\lib\net6.0\NModbus.dll</HintPath>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image: Example output]

You can also use this method to exclude `ProjectReferences` but as yet they have not extended this support to `PackageReferences`.

In the new project templates you can still add `AssemblyReferences` through the *Reference Manager* that you can access from the `Add` menu when you right click the project file in the solution explorer
[image]

User the `Browse` section to locate the assemblies that you want to reference.

[image: Reference Manager]

---

There is an open GitHub Issue for this support to be added to `PackageReferences`: [Exclude entire packages from single-file #25411](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25411) however it becomes complicated in general for NuGet packages because the package can contain embedded content and compilable code files as well, they do not only contain dlls. On top of this, Nuget packages can have multiple dependencies so the end result might be very similar to

```
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```

---

You can also use a Post Processing target as described here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25411#issuecomment-1488303691 to selectively exclude files from the publish output based on the file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
      <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NModbus.Serial" Version="3.0.81" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <Target Name="ExplicitRemoveFromFilesToBundle" BeforeTargets="GenerateSingleFileBundle" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBundle">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToRemoveFromBundle Include="@(FilesToBundle)" Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(Filename)').ToLower().Contains('nmodbus.serial')) AND ('%(Extension)' == '.dll')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="FilesToRemoveFromBundle '@(FilesToRemoveFromBundle)'" Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToBundle Remove="@(FilesToRemoveFromBundle)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CopyFilesToRemoveFromBundle" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToRemoveFromBundle)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
    <Message Text="Copied files to remove from bundle to '$(PublishDir)'" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious to know why this answer was downvoted

Comment: @Cid there are some people here that just downvote because they can;)